# Web api GET (all) with optional parameters from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, get, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web API GET (all) method with multiple optional parameters.
I'm trying this with 1 parameter first but eventually I want 5 optional parameters.
Starting with 1 parameter I have 2 situations: parameter is filled in and parameter is not filled in.

Parameter is filled in

```
from r in db.requests
where r.status == status
select new Models.Request
```

Parameter is not filled in

```
from r in db.requests
select new Models.Request
```

I can not get both situations to work together so my question is:
How can I combine these 2 situations?

Controller

```
public IEnumerable<Request> Get(string status = "")
    {
        var requests = from r in db.requests
                       //where r.status == status
                       select new Models.Request
                       {
                           ID = r.ID,
                           ...more properties
                           };
            return (IEnumerable<Request>)requests;
    }
```

Route

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "API Default",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
from r in db.requests
where r.status == status || status == ""
select new Models.Request
```

If status is empty string second part of the expression is true and all items will be returned no matter  the value of the first part. Otherwise the first part of the expression filters the result set.

Comment: Thanks! This works.
So I assume that, for more parameters, I should do:
where r.status == status || status == "" && r.param2 == param2 || param2 == "" && ......

Comment: @Mtthiask Well, this is not that easy. If you want to do the same trick with the second alike parameter you should use parentethes: `(r.status == status || status == "") && (r.param2 == param2 || param2 == "")`. However in this case if the expression in first parentheses is true, the second will not be evaluated. So be mindful of what the outcome has to be.